# Computing the kernel of some Artin-Map

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields, prime-ideals, ramification

let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ and $L = K(i)$. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of K.

I would like to show that the kernel of the Artin-Map $\phi_{L/K}: I_K \rightarrow Gal(L/K)$ is $P_K$, where $I_K$ denotes the group of all fractional Ideals from the ring of integers of $K$ and $P_K$ denots the group of all prinicipal ideals.

Because I´m new to this topic, I want to do it without class field theory, but recently I read a lot about the frobenius-element/artin-symbol of a prime ideal.

So far I thought about the following:
I guess I can compute the frobenius-element/artin-symbol of every prime $\mathfrak{P}$ from $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ which lies about a integer prime $p \neq 2,5$. I think this can be useful since $K(i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$.
I also know that $2\mathcal{O}_K = (2, 1 +\sqrt{-5})^{2}$ and $5\mathcal{O}_K = (\sqrt(-5))^2$.

Since $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian, the Artin-Symbol of $\mathfrak{P}$ depends only on the underlying prime integer p, for which $(p) = \mathfrak{P} \cap \mathbb{Z}$.

The Artin-symbol of every prime integer $p \equiv 1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\ mod\ 20$ should be the field-automorphism $\sigma_p$ which maps $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^{p}$.

Further, $<\sigma_3>$ fixes $K$ and $<\sigma_9>$ fixes $L$.  Now I know

$p$ splits completely in $K$ resp. $L$ iff $\sigma_p$ fixes $K$ resp. $L$.

Now let $p \equiv 11,13,17,19\ mod\ 20$ a prime integer.

Then $p$ doesn´t split in $K$, which mean (in this case) there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ from $\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $p$ with inertial degree $f(\mathfrak{p}|p) = 2$.

Since $p$ doesn´t split completely in $L$ either, it can only split into one or two prime ideals. But $|<\sigma_{p}|_{L}>| = 2$, where $\sigma_{p}|_{L}$ is the restriciton to $L$. That means that $p$ splits into 2 prime ideals in $L$. That means there a prime ideals $\mathfrak{P}_1,\mathfrak{P}_2$ in $L$ with $p\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{P}_1\mathfrak{P}_2$. 
But also $p\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p}$ with $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in $K$. 
Then I can see that $f(\mathfrak{P}_i|\mathfrak{p}) = 1$, which means that $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in $L$. Is this right so far?

Now let $p \equiv 1,3,7,9\ mod\ 20$ be a prime integer.

$p$ splits completely in $K$, which means there a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_1,\mathfrak{p}_2$ in $K$ with $p\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2$. So $f(\mathfrak{p}_i|p) = 1$.

Now for $p \equiv 1,9\ mod\ 20$.

$p$ splits completely in $L$, which means there a prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}_1,\mathfrak{P}_2,\mathfrak{P}_3,\mathfrak{P}_4$ in $L$ with $p\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{P}_1\mathfrak{P}_2\mathfrak{P}_3\mathfrak{P}_4$. So $f(\mathfrak{P}_i|p) = 1$ and hence $f(\mathfrak{P}_i|\mathfrak{p}_j) = 1$.

So every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$, lying over a prime $p \equiv 1,9\ mod\ 20$ splits completely in $L$, is that right?

When I do the same for $p \equiv 3,7\ mod\ 20$ then I get that every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$, lying over such a prime integer $p$, doesn´t split in $L$, because $f(\mathfrak{p}|p) = 1$, but also $|<\sigma_{p}|_{L}>| = 2$, which means $p\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{P}_1\mathfrak{P}_2$. Therefore $f(\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}) = 2$.

According to my calculations only the prim ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$, which lie over a prime integer $p \equiv 3,7\ mod\ p$ doesn´t split in $L$. can somebody confirm this?

Now, except for those prime ideals lying over 2 and 5, I can tell which prime ideals (dependent on the underlying prime integer) in $K$ splits completely in $L$, which means mapping to the 1 in $Gal(L/K).

Now, how can I check that those prime ideals are exactly the principal prime fractional ideals? And which prime ideals generate $P_K$?

Thanks in advance
Julian

Comment: Everything boils down to showing that prime ideals with norm $\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ are principal. This is elementary. You have to show that primes $p$ that split satisfy  $p = x^2 + 5y^2$ if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $2p = x^2 + 5y^2$ if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

Comment: When you talk about norm, do you mean $\mathcal{N}(\mathfrak{p}) = |\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}|$ for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K$?

Comment: Yes. Principal ideals $(x,+y\sqrt{-5})$ have norm $p = x^2 + 5y^2$. The nonprincipal primes lie in the class of the prime ideal above $2$ . . .

Comment: Ah, now I see: $p\mathcal{O}_K =(x+y\sqrt{-5})(x-y\sqrt{-5}) = (x^2 +5y^2)$ and this is exactly the case iff $p \equiv 1,9\ mod\ 20$. And for $p \equiv 11,13,17,19\ mod\ 20$ $p\mathcal{O}_K$ remains prime and is principal. Now I only need to compute $\varphi(2\mathcal{O}_K)$ and $\varphi(5\mathcal{O}_K)$.

Two another questions: Is $P_K$ generated by the principal prime ideals and how can I see in which ways $2\mathcal{O}_K,5\mathcal{O}_K$ splits in $L$? 

And thank you for your help.

Comment: a) No: the product of two nonprincipal prime ideals is principal. b) 2 is inert in one subfields, 5 splits in another.

Comment: Then in the next step I want to show that the kernel of $\varphi_{L/K}$ is exactly $P_K$. Because I know excatly which prime ideals maps to $1 \in Gal(L/K$, I can see that every product of principal prime ideals will be mapped to the $1$. Every Product of even many non-principal prime ideals will be mapped to the $1$, too. Because the class number of $K$ is $2$ every product of non-principal ideals must be a principal ideal. Can I conclude from this that every non-principal(resp. principal) Ideal is the product of some principal ideals and uneven(resp. even) man non-principal ideals?